# How to Refresh health checks ui page?

Tags: asp.net-core, health-check

Is there a way to auto refresh the healthchecks ui page? when I focus another place and return back it refreshes but when I did nothing It doesn't refresh the status

Comment: please add your code

Comment: When do you want to refresh? Can you provide me with your code and the problems encountered?

Comment: I've hit this issue too - bug report here: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/1829